# Enable a button in the parent wx.Frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I need help to enable a button in the parent wx.Frame, here i have an example of two classed first class **mainFrame** has two buttons first one **m_buttonlogin** to launch the second wx.Frame class instance **loginFrame**
and another disabled button.
what i need to do is upon successful login in the child Frame the disabled button turns enabled in the main frame.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Jun 17 2015)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import wx
import wx.xrc

###########################################################################
## Class mainFrame
###########################################################################

class mainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_buttonlogin = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Login", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_buttonlogin, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_buttondisabled = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Dsiabled", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_buttondisabled.Enable( False )

        bSizer1.Add( self.m_buttondisabled, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_buttonlogin.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnLogin )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def OnLogin( self, event ):
        loginFrame.Show(self)
        event.Skip()


###########################################################################
## Class loginFrame
###########################################################################

class loginFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_textCtrlusername = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_textCtrlusername, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_textCtrlpassword = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_textCtrlpassword, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_buttonOK = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_buttonOK, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer2 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_buttonOK.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOK )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def OnOK( self, event ):
        # Enable "m_buttondisabled" button in the mainFrame
        event.Skip()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An simple way to achieve this is to make use of the `parent` attribute in the `loginFrame`.

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

###########################################################################
## Class mainFrame
###########################################################################

class mainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_buttonlogin = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Login", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_buttonlogin, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_buttondisabled = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Disabled", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_buttondisabled.Enable( False )

        bSizer1.Add( self.m_buttondisabled, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_buttonlogin.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnLogin )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def OnLogin( self, event ):
        loginFrame(self).Show()
        event.Skip()


###########################################################################
## Class loginFrame
###########################################################################

class loginFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.parent = parent
        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_textCtrlusername = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_textCtrlusername, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_textCtrlpassword = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_textCtrlpassword, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_buttonOK = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_buttonOK, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer2 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_buttonOK.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOK )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def OnOK( self, event ):
        # Enable "m_buttondisabled" button in the mainFrame
        self.parent.m_buttondisabled.Enable( True )
        self.parent.m_buttonlogin.Enable( False)
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
frame = mainFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches to this issue. One of the easiest methods is to just make your login frame into a dialog so you can easily show it modally. Then add a class instance attribute that you can use to determine if the `OK` button has been pressed. In this case, I will use `self.ok` for my attribute.

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

###########################################################################
## Class mainFrame
###########################################################################

class mainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_buttonlogin = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Login", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_buttonlogin, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_buttondisabled = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Dsiabled", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_buttondisabled.Enable( False )

        bSizer1.Add( self.m_buttondisabled, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_buttonlogin.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnLogin )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def OnLogin( self, event ):
        login = loginDialog(self)
        dlg = loginDialog(self)
        dlg.ShowModal()

        if dlg.ok:
            self.m_buttondisabled.Enable(True)

        event.Skip()


###########################################################################
## Class loginFrame
###########################################################################

class loginDialog( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, 
                            size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.ok = False

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_textCtrlusername = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_textCtrlusername, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_textCtrlpassword = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_textCtrlpassword, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_buttonOK = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"OK", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer2.Add( self.m_buttonOK, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer2 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_buttonOK.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOK )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    def MakeModal(self, modal=True):
        if modal and not hasattr(self, '_disabler'):
            self._disabler = wx.WindowDisabler(self)
        if not modal and hasattr(self, '_disabler'):
            del self._disabler

        self.Show()


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def OnOK( self, event ):
        self.ok = True
        # Enable "m_buttondisabled" button in the mainFrame
        event.Skip()
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = mainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

By doing this, I can check if the dialog instance's `ok` attribute is `True` or `False` and act accordingly by enabling (or not) the button.

An alternative would be to use wxPython's built-in pubsub module:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.pubsub.html
- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: Hello Mike,  Thanks for the code and for pubsub reference the logic worked. but for pubsub it didn't work for me, i think it is a version issue.

Comment: Which version of wxPython are you using? I could show a simple example